# How to include an auto-number in a field

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a requirement where the user wants to see the value of an auto-generated number appended with the name in the same name field.

Example:

User is creating a record and entering value 'ABC' in the name field. Upon saving, the user should see the value 'X-000 ABC' in the name field (X-000 is an auto number in this object).

I used a Record-Triggered Flow but unfortunately it's working only on update (not when the user creates a record).

Any advise or help is highly appreciated.

Comment: you should use [edit] and show how you have defined the Flow. Note that the auto-number field won't be available until the record is saved

Answer (score 2):

A simple formula field should be able to handle this.

As formula fields are computed values (computed every time the record is accessed) rather than stored values, the result should always be correct.

It'd simply be a concatenation of your record's name and auto-number fields (formula field type = text)

e.g. `autonumberField__c + ' ' + nameField__c`

Comment: Hi Derek, Thanks...
I just want to append this auto-generated number to a field and update the same field.
Example: You entered the field Name__c = 'Derek'. Upon save, you should see this Name__c field as 'X-001 Derek'.
I wrote a Flow, but it keeps on appending the name every time I save.